# Calculating the Bekenstein-Hawking entropy for 1+1 black hole with dilaton background

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, string-theory, wess-zumino-witten

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.03048) the Bekenstein-Hawking entropy of a 1+1 black hole which described by the $SL_k(2,\mathbb{R})/U(1)$ WZW cigar geometry is given by the following formula appearing in eq. (5.7):

$$S=2\pi e^{-2\Phi_0}$$

But according to Bekenstein-Hawking formula the entropy is given by:

$$S_{BH}=\frac{k_Bc^3A}{4G\hbar}$$

We use natural units $c=\hbar=k_B=1$, So:
$$S_{BH}=\frac{A}{4G}$$

The $d$ dimensional Newton constant $G$ is given by the string scale $l_s$ and string coupling $g_s$ in the following way:
$$G_d=l_s^{d-2}g_s^2$$
for the 1+1 case we left with:
$$G_2 = g_s^2.$$
Under dilaton field background, the coupling that measured from infinity is given by the asymptotic value of the dilaton $\Phi$ which we denote by $\Phi_0$ so:
$$g_s=e^{\Phi_0}$$
Now, togather with a surface area of a 1d spatial line that is given by:
$$A=2$$
The entropy should be:

$$S_{BH}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-2\Phi_0}$$

What is the source of the extra $4\pi$ factor such that $S_{BH}$ will fit exactly $S$?